# Create Add-In for Outlook 2013 for add a Button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

Good morning,
my company is looking for a solution in order to distribute an add-in for Outlook 2013 that add a button in the ribbon. I want to create an add-in for Outlook 2013 and I saw that is possible using Visual Studio (I use VS 2013 or 2010) but I don't understand how to add a button in the ribbon (in particular in Home section) and execute a macro when I click on the button (the macro is already created). I read this tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx and this worked. Someone can help me with some piece of code(c#)?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Simone, were you actually able to add a button to the Home tab?  I am trying to use VB, but I'm still not seeing how to add a button to an existing tab (ribbon) rather than the Add-In ribbon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSTO provides two main ways for customizing the Ribbon UI:

1. Using the Ribbon designer. See [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using the Ribbon Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx) for more information.
2. Using the Ribbon XML markup. See [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx) for more information.

You need to specify the idMso attribute of the built-in tab if you need to add your custom controls there. See [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798) for control IDs.

Finally, I'd suggest moving your VBA macro to the add-in. It will improve the overall performance and allows to use the BCL classes (a wide varioety of controls and components) for getting the job done. Moveover, you will be able to deplay the add-in easily. VBA macros are not designed for deployiong on multiple PCs.

Comment: Thanks for your help Eugene. How can I move the macro in the add-In and the assign the macro to the button?

Comment: And after that I create my VSTO project, how can I use it to distribute as add-in?

Comment: See [Deploying an Office Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Eugene!!! Now I create my add-in. I'd like that when I click a button on the ribbon I can reply the email and display it. With the macro I can use the reply method. Do you know how to do using c#?

Comment: I'd suggest asking separate questions in new threads. So, other users may easily find the answer.

Comment: Eugene, how does the Ribbon XML interact with the identifier for the Home tab?  I think the identifier is TabMail for the 'Home' tab.   Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ah!  The idMso you refer to is an XML attribute of the 'tab' tag.  Sorry, I didn't make the connection.  I'll leave my above comment in case anyone else is confused.